# Using stroke property in CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to recreate a button from an image in code. The button uses font weight of 900 and the font Inter which can be found in Google fonts. The actual text color is transparent, but it contains a stroke of 1px with a slight yellow coloring. I have almost recreated the button perfectly, but on the A the stroke actually shows the bottom bar of the A. To all my CSS experts, is there a way to fix this?

Here is the image:

[image: Original Button Image]

Here is what my code is looking like visually:

[image: Error]

Here is my code

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;900&display=swap');

.button {
    color: black;
    font-size: 34px;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px rgb(253, 230, 16);
    -webkit-text-fill-color: rgb(2, 17, 42);
    background-color: rgb(2, 17, 42);
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif!important;
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">ACCESS EVENT</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the fault of the font and how they draw the `A`. If you remove the font it works fine

**Edit** it seems if you use a different import link it works fine

```css
@import url('https://rsms.me/inter/inter.css');
.button {
  color: black;
  font-size: 34px;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px rgb(253, 230, 16);
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgb(2, 17, 42);
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif!important;
  background-color: rgb(2, 17, 42);
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">ACCESS EVENT</button>
```

Comment: I have to use this font.

Comment: It works using this link `@import url('https://rsms.me/inter/inter.css');`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!